# pole placement in LMI regions

Tags: convex-optimization, dynamical-systems, linear-matrix-inequality

In [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6bad/35a325931e9c75f3a4db1a3dbfa91ca3e49a.pdf) paper, the authors elegantly present a LMI region as a subset $\mathcal{D}$ of the complex plane

$$ \mathcal{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | L + z\cdot M + \bar{z}\cdot M^T < 0 \}$$ where $L = L^T$ and $M$ are some real matrices. Then, they proceed to say that a real matrix $A$ is $\mathcal{D}$ stable (that is, it has all eigenvalues in $\mathcal{D}$) iff there $\exists$ a symmetric positive definite matrix $X$, such that
$$ L \otimes X + M \otimes (X\cdot A) + M^T \otimes (A^T\cdot X) < 0$$ where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. How can I prove this?

### My ideea

Indeed, for $L = 0$ and $M = 1$ the LMI region is the left complex plane and indeed the above condition becomes the well known Lyapunov stability requirement for the dynamical system $\dot{x} = A\cdot x$ which is equivalent with the eigenvalues of $A$ being in the left complex plane! Am I suppose to see this as some sort of transformation of the imaginary axis in a convex region?

Comment: The proof can be found in the Appendix of the full version of the paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3022474_H_Design_with_Pole_Placement_Constraints_an_LMI_Approach

Comment: @shamisen thank you!